# checking if a string is a palindrome

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to check if a string is a palindrome in bash. Here is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a string: " string
if [[ $string|rev == $string ]]; then
    echo "Palindrome"
fi
```

Now, `echo $string|rev` gives reversed string. My logic was to use it in the condition for `if`. That did not work out so well.

So, how can I store the "returned value" from `rev` into a variable? *or use it directly in a condition?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another variation without `echo` and unnecessary quoting within `[[ ... ]]`:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a string: " string
if [[ $(rev <<< "$string") == "$string" ]]; then
    echo Palindrome
fi
```

Comment: and how do I assign it to a variable? `var=$(rev <<< $string)`?

Comment: Yes! (which you could just run and see for yourself)

Comment: Consider quoting `<<< "$string"` or strings like `a<space><space>a` won't work unless you use `bash 4.4` or later.

Answer (score 4):

A bash-only implementation:

```
is_palindrome () { 
    local word=$1
    local len=$((${#word} - 1))
    local i
    for ((i=0; i <= (len/2); i++)); do
        [[ ${word:i:1} == ${word:len-i:1} ]] || return 1
    done
    return 0
}

for word in hello kayak; do
    if is_palindrome $word; then
        echo $word is a palindrome
    else
        echo $word is NOT a palindrome
    fi
done
```

Inspired by gniourf_gniourf:

```
is_palindrome() {
  (( ${#1} <= 1 )) && return 0
  [[ ${1:0:1} != ${1: -1} ]] && return 1
  is_palindrome ${1:1: 1}
}
```

I bet the performance of this truly recursive call really sucks.

Comment: Or shorter with less local variables: `is_palindrome() { local w=$1; while [[ $w = ??* && ${w:0:1} = "${w: -1}" ]]; do w=${w:1:-1}; done; ((${#w}<2)); }`.

Comment: Shorter, but not necessarily clearer. Anyone feel like benchmarking?

Comment: It's very clear, and close to a recursive style. Yours is more a procedural style. Depending on point of view and background, clarity is subjective.

Comment: Yeah, the recursive version sucks in Bash (since Bash doesn't have tail-recursion optimization) and is subject to nesting errors. Yet the one I gave has better performance than your original (about 20% on my machine) `;)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(command substitution)`:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a string: " string
if [[ "$(echo "$string" | rev)" == "$string" ]]; then
    echo "Palindrome"
fi
```

Comment: and storing it in a variable would be `var=$($string|rev)` ?

Comment: You can find more on this if you look on Google... http://phoxis.org/2010/01/26/bash-palindrome/

Comment: @Harry Seriously, mate? :D I was trying to avoid Professor Google

Comment: No, `var=$(echo "$string" | rev)`

Comment: @LittleChild `var=$(echo "$string" | rev)`. The role of `echo` in your command is not to write out the result of `$string | rev`, but to write the value of `$string` to `rev` so that `rev` can write the reversed version out.

Comment: @tripleee okay so echo returns the string value of the command. Am I correct?

Comment: With bash, you can write `var=$(rev <<<"$string")` instead: a [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the best implementation, but if you need something with pure **sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

#get character <str> <num_of_char>. Please, remember that indexing is from 1
get_character() {
  echo "$1" | cut -c "$2"
}

for i in $(seq $((${#1} / 2))); do
  if [ "$(get_character "$1" "$i")" != "$(get_character "$1" $((${#1} - i + 1)))" ]; then
    echo "NO"
    exit 0
  fi
done

echo "YES"
```

and canonical way with bash as well

```
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#1} / 2 - 1))); do
  if [ "${1:$i:1}" != "${1:$((${#1} - i - 1)):1}" ]; then
    echo "NO"
    exit 0
  fi
done

echo "YES"
```

Answer (score 0):

Skipping all punctuation marks and letter case.

input:He lived as a devil, eh?

output:Palindrome

input:Madam, I am Adam.

output:Not Palindrome

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -x

read -p "Enter a sentence" message

message=$(echo "$message" | \

sed -e '
s/[[:space:]]//g
s/[[:punct:]]//g
s/\!//g
y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
' )

i=0
while read -n 1 letter
do
tempArray[i]="$letter"
((i++))    
done < <(echo "$message")
i=0

counter=$((${#message}-1))

while [ "$i" -ne $((${#message}/2)) ]
do
if [ "${tempArray[$i]}" = "${tempArray[$counter]}" ]
then 
((i++))
((counter--))
else echo -n "Not ";break
fi
done

echo "Palindrome"
exit
```